# Unable to resolve user environment variable correctly

Tags: asp-classic, environment-variables, user-profile, wsh

I am trying to resolve `%USERPROFILE%` using `WScript.Shell`. When I create a vbs file and run directly from Windows, I get the correct path for the logged-in user `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator` but it gets resolved to `C:\Documents and Settings\Default User` instead of logged-in user when I used it inside my classic ASP webapp running on the local machine on IIS.

The code I used is as below

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
var userPath = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%");
```

Is there a permission/setting which I need to check to get correct value of `USERPROFILE` when retrieving value from the webapp?

PS: I am using javascript to code.

Comment: What makes you think "Default User" is not the correct value?  ASP does not run in the current interactive session, it runs as a service.

Comment: I should have written 'Desirable' instead of 'Correct'. So is there anyway to retrieve logged-in user's profile from ASP?

Comment: Perhaps it might be better if you described why that is desirable?  What possible coupling is there between an ASP application and a current interactive session (note that can be more than one or even none)?  What sort of information are you looking for from the profile?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I want to retrieve logged-in user's user profile (preferably Document folder) and would that path to save a file to. Each user logs into the system using their own account and I don't want anyone to see anyone else's file. Does this make sense? I didn't understand your question regarding coupling between ASP app and current session.

Comment: There are lots of possible misunderstandings you could have and I'm trying to draw out which ones you have.  There is no relationship between an ASP application and any current interactive session on the server.  This leads me to the conclusion that you actually want to load the profile for the user to client machine (where the browser is running not the server) and to somehow put files where that users My Documents is (I assume at least you understand that this means My Documents has to roam about on a network share).  That just isn't going to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP does not know what user is logged in, it runs under a generic anonymous internet user account.

If you want IIS to know the current user, you will have to remove rights for the anonymous user on the directory of your site. This will force IIS to show your users a login screen.
After they log in, the thread for that session will run under the logged on user (so make sure that user has rights). You can now use request.servervariables("AUTH_USER") to get the username.

Erik

Answer (score 0):

Select windows authentication for this site (IIS configuration) in stead of anonymous this kind of security is refered to as NTLM in IIS and the rights are given using standard NTFS permissions on the folders and files, when using IE as browser no prompt is given to log on (single sign on), if you use FF you have to log on once per session. Here a ASP page which shows all the variables available server side. You can pass these variables to your client code if needed, better not work with ActiveX for authentication (and for most of the time).

```
'file servervaraibles.asp
<html>
<%@language=VBScript%>
<%
  With Response
    .Expires=-1
    .Clear
  End With
  dim teller
  response.write "<h1>Servervariables</h1>"
  response.write "<table>"
  teller = 1
  for each subkey in Request.Servervariables
    response.write "<tr><td>"
    response.write teller
    response.write "</td><td>"
    response.write (Request.Servervariables.Key(teller))
    response.write "</td><td>"
    response.write (Request.Servervariables.Item(teller))
    response.write "</td></tr>"
    teller = teller + 1 
  next
  response.write "</table>"
  response.write request.servervariables("path_translated") & "<br>"
  response.write "USER cookie:" & Request.Cookies("USER") & "<br>"
  response.write "USER Sessionvariable:" & Session("USER") & "<br>"
%>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question I think you are asking is: no.

ASP can not load and unload user profiles on demand and even it could that assumes the server has a profile for every user (each user has to have interactively logged on to the server at least once).

The best you can do is turn off anonymous access on the application so that the server variable "AUTH_USER" contains a user name unique to that user.  Create a common network share for each domain that may appear in the AUTH_USER (you probably only have one).  Create under that network share a folder for each user and grant appropriate access rights.

Now you can parse AUTH_USER and determine which root path you can load and save files to for the current request user.